# android cropping drawable

Tags: android, drawable, crop, rounded-corners

I have a small project in which i download images from internet in the form of drawable and use them in Imageview for which i have provided functionality similar to an Imagebutton but without the gray edges.

The question is that is there any functionality in Android(similar to iphone) by which we can crop the drawable from edges to make them rounded edged drawable...

Even if its a "not-tested-neither-recommended" method, do let me know... i would like to work on this a bit... thanx in advance folks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is probably the link you're looking for: [How should I give images rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705239/how-should-i-give-images-rounded-corners-in-android)

I tried doing it with a  drawable and nested  and  elements, but wasn't able to get the image drawable to show properly.  Not sure if there's a way to get this working or not.

Comment: wow!!! i tried searching but without success... thanx mike... i'll try doin it the way mentioned...