# Android Custom Component View w/Rounded Corners

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to create a View with rounded corners (and a background color of choice) that I can reuse with different background colors; hard to explain, so here's my code:

*/app/src/com/packagename/whatever/CustomDrawableView.java*

```
package com.packagename.whatever;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.PaintDrawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class CustomDrawableView extends View {
    private PaintDrawable mDrawable;
    int radius;

    private void init(AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.RoundedRect);
        radius = a.getInteger(R.styleable.RoundedRect_radius, 0);
    }

    public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

        mDrawable = new PaintDrawable();
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        mDrawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
        mDrawable.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Here's the XML to display the custom component:
*/app/res/layout/test.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ny="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.packagename.whatever"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <com.packagename.whatever.CustomDrawableView
        android:id="@+id/custom"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#b80010"
        ny:radius="50"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

I'm wanting the red box to have 50px rounded corners, but as you'll see, it does not:

[image: Red box without rounded corners]

The idea is that I could easily change the background color in the XML and automatically have a nice View with rounded corners, without having to create multiple drawables.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set your corner radius and color into the background drawable.

Here is one way that would work.  Grab the color you set in android:background, then use it to create a new drawable that you set into the background in the constructor.  This will work as long as you only set android:background to a color value.

```
   public CustomDrawableView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);

        // pull out the background color
        int color = attrs.getAttributeIntValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "background", 0xffffffff);

        // create a new background drawable, set the color and radius and set it in place
        mDrawable = new PaintDrawable();
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(color);
        mDrawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
        setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
    }
```

If you override onDraw, make sure you call super.onDraw(canvas) first to get the background drawn.

Answer (score 3):

given a simple shapedrawable like this:

```
public ShapeDrawable Sd(int s){

float[] outerR = new float[] { 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12 };
ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new RoundRectShape(outerR, null,null));

            mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(s);
return mDrawable;
}
```

you can do the following:

```
    LinearLayout l=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.testLayout);
l.setBackgroundDrawable(Sd(0xff74AC23));
```

where the 12's represent the radius.
you could apply this to any view for a background drawable.

Comment: if you already have the buttons colored and you need to round corner them i use this code   Resources res = this.getResources();  button2.setBackgroundDrawable(this.Sd(res.getColor(R.color.color1x2)));

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this question: [How do I set the rounded corner radius of a color drawable using xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122199/how-do-i-set-the-rounded-corner-radius-of-a-color-drawable-using-xml)

And perhaps also these two:

[How to add rounded corner to a drawable I'm using as a background in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3150514/how-to-add-rounded-corner-to-a-drawable-im-using-as-a-background-in-android)
[How should I give images rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705239/how-should-i-give-images-rounded-corners-in-android)

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm trying to dynamically set the background color. Your first two links are the methods I normally use, but only allow for a static bg, hence my problem. The third link might do the trick... I'll take a look. :)

Comment: @iamkoa calling `setBackgoundColor()` afterwards does not work?

Comment: Yes, but this would require that you add a android:background drawable, then manually override the background color of the drawable in Java, right? I'm looking for a solution that allows everything to be in one XML call.