# How to make layout with rounded corners..?

Tags: android, xml, image, layout, android-shapedrawable

How can I make a layout with rounded corners? I want to apply rounded corners to my `LinearLayout`.

Comment: you just need to set rounded image as background of layout else make shape as said in first comment

Comment: you just need to search over SO... you will find alot of asnwers ..

Comment: the corners are obscured for me

Comment: Google have new framework,
new technologies is better [Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054562/how-to-make-the-corners-of-a-button-round/64087445#64087445)

Answer (score 1269, accepted):

1: Define **layout_bg.xml** in drawables:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

2: Add `layout_bg.xml` as background to your layout

```
android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
```

Comment: This doesn't work. as you've set, it's the background, so the content overrides the rounded corners, and if you have content that draws on the corners, you won't see them being rounded.

Comment: Almost always, my content never cover the corners. This works perfectly.

Comment: How do you avoid the error `Element shape doesn't have the required attribute android:layout_height`?

Comment: How to make it as circle..it is coming as Rectangle

Comment: `Element shape doesn't have the required attribute android:layout_height` The reason the error was shown because layout_bg.xml was not inside the drawable folder.

Comment: Somehow the comment saying it doesn't work at all (which is correct) has 100 upvotes but the question only has 4 downvotes... what is going on with this site?

Comment: for those who got error "Element shape doesn't ... ",  put the xml to `drawable` folder!

Comment: Something is going very wrong when a wrong answer like this has so many votes

Comment: @androiddeveloper what's the solution?

Comment: @Anirudh Look at my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650467/878126 . Note that I haven't tested it in a long time, and don't remember how it works anymore. I hope it can help.

Comment: @nhouser9: actually it's more like "It works, but be warned that your foreground/content might draw in the corners". So depending on the use case it might 100% work. I'm glad the answer has not so many downvotes because it is useful, and I'm glad that the comment has a hundred upvotes because it is easy to spot the limitation with this solution. Best of both worlds.

Comment: this doesn't work while dealing with multiple linear layouts at once having different background colors

Comment: This may cause radius not appearing issue on the corners(while the shape is rectangle) while the solid color is anything else than white, so try layer list with two items, with the first rectangle item with solid color and second one with solid color you wanted.

Comment: @androiddeveloper do adding `padding` solve the issue in all case ?

Comment: @micaball Well it depends on which case. If you want the content to be rounded, this won't work, as I've written. If you just want a rectangle of content within something rounded that's ok I guess... You can check my last solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23650467/878126 . I think it will cover all options you want

Comment: For the people how are saying that it cover their content, the problem is that you have to add this as a background of the nested layout. example. A outside LinearLayout with transparent background and then an inside LinearLayout with this drawable set as background, and you can always set padding and margin to fit your needs.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding 0dp paddings will have any effect

Comment: **android:backgroundTint="@color/your_color"** if you want to modify color.

Answer (score 186):

**For API 21+, Use Clip Views**

Rounded outline clipping was added to the `View` class in API 21. See this [training doc](https://developer.android.com/training/material/shadows-clipping.html#Clip) or this [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClipToOutline(boolean)) for more info.

This in-built feature makes rounded corners very easy to implement. It works on any view or layout and supports proper clipping.

**Here's What To Do:**

- Create a rounded shape drawable and set it as your view's background:
  `android:background="@drawable/round_outline"`
- Clip to outline in code: `setClipToOutline(true)`

The documentation used to say that you can set `android:clipToOutline="true"` the XML, but [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=164125) is now finally resolved and the documentation now correctly states that you can only do this in code.

**What It Looks Like:**

[image: examples with and without clipToOutline]

**Special Note About ImageViews**

`setClipToOutline()` only works when the View's background is set to a shape drawable. If this background shape exists, View treats the background's outline as the borders for clipping and shadowing purposes.

This means that if you want to round the corners on an ImageView with `setClipToOutline()`, your image must come from `android:src` instead of `android:background` (since background is used for the rounded shape). If you MUST use background to set your image instead of src, you can use this nested views workaround:

- Create an outer layout with its background set to your shape drawable
- Wrap that layout around your ImageView (with no padding)
- The ImageView (including anything else in the layout) will now be clipped to the outer layout's rounded shape.

Comment: Does not work on API less than 21. Cant wait till I can only support API 21.

Comment: Using 'setClipToOutline' works, but it also removes the frame itself (the drawable you use for the background). Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Did you read my note about using `src=@drawable...` instead of `background=@drawable`? You can either do that or nest your ImageView inside a container view that holds the shape outline.

Comment: Everybody comment on that bug---it's almost three years old and shows no sign of getting fixed anytime this decade. Let's put some pressure on.

Comment: How can this bug not be fixed yet

Comment: how to use this function on lower API's below 21?

Comment: @FebinMathew You can't.

Comment: I have my imageView inside NestedScrollView, inside Constaint Layout. I use android:src to put image into ImageView. I use clipToOutline = true on all 3 layouts.  I use shape drawable with rounded corners. But imageview's shape != his root layour shape

Comment: Just to note: it doesn't work if we set only bottom corners in our drawable shape

Comment: in case of recyclerview, some items lose the rounded corners

Comment: Warning: `RemoteViews` does not support setClipToOutline and throw an error along the lines of `view: [YOUR VIEW] can't use method with RemoteViews: setClipToOutline(boolean)` if you use it.

Comment: Where in the code do I need to call setClipToOutline() ?

Comment: @JoshHansen The bug was resolved in API 31.

Answer (score 97):

Here's a copy of a XML file  to create a drawable with a white background, black border and rounded corners:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
        <solid android:color="#ffffffff"/>    

        <stroke android:width="3dp"
                android:color="#ff000000"
                />

        <padding android:left="1dp"
                 android:top="1dp"
                 android:right="1dp"
                 android:bottom="1dp"
                 /> 

        <corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
         android:topLeftRadius="7dp" android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
    </shape>
```

save it as a xml file in the drawable directory,
Use it like you would use any drawable background(icon or resource file) using its resource name (R.drawable.your_xml_name)

Comment: Loved the possibility of rounding specific corners

Comment: This answer is pretty much the answer as above. The only real change here is the definition of each corner radius, and given its the same value for each corner i would have written it in one line instead: `<corners android:radius="7dp" />` :)

Comment: this is the BEST answer for me, as it covers the availability of rounding specific corners ... good job, works 100%

Comment: The ImageView's corners are not rounded (clipped), how do I solve this?

Answer (score 53):

Use CardView in android v7 support library.
Though it's a bit heavy, it solves all problem, and easy enough.
Not like the set drawable background method, it could clip subviews successfully.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">
    <YOUR_LINEARLAYOUT_HERE>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Much better for everybody who can "afford" it than anything else. It baffles me that such a basic thing isn't part of standard Android views, being a staple in CSS for almost any web browser

Answer (score 31):

I have done this way:

Check Screenshot:

[image: Relative layout Background]

Create **drawable** file named with `custom_rectangle.xml` in **drawable** folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="10dip" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="@android:color/white" />

</shape>
```

Now apply **Rectangle background** on **View**:

```
mView.setBackground(R.drawlable.custom_rectangle);
```

**Done**

Comment: This doesn't work. as you've set, it's the background, so the content overrides the rounded corners, and if you have content that draws on the corners, you won't see them being rounded.

Answer (score 31):

I think a better way to do it is to merge 2 things:

1. make a bitmap of the layout, as shown [**here**](http://nadavfima.com/android-snippet-inflate-a-layout-draw-to-a-bitmap/).
2. make a rounded drawable from the bitmap, as shown [**here**](http://rahulswackyworld.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/android-drawables-with-rounded_7.html)
3. set the drawable on an imageView.

This will handle cases that other solutions have failed to solve, such as having content that has corners.

I think it's also a bit more GPU-friendly, as it shows a single layer instead of 2 .

The only better way is to make a totally customized view, but that's a lot of code and might take a lot of time. I think that what I suggested here is the best of both worlds.

Here's a snippet of how it can be done:

**RoundedCornersDrawable.java**

```
/**
 * shows a bitmap as if it had rounded corners. based on :
 * http://rahulswackyworld.blogspot.co.il/2013/04/android-drawables-with-rounded_7.html
 * easy alternative from support library: RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create( ...) ; 
 */
public class RoundedCornersDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {

    private final BitmapShader bitmapShader;
    private final Paint p;
    private final RectF rect;
    private final float borderRadius;

    public RoundedCornersDrawable(final Resources resources, final Bitmap bitmap, final float borderRadius) {
        super(resources, bitmap);
        bitmapShader = new BitmapShader(getBitmap(), Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        final Bitmap b = getBitmap();
        p = getPaint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setShader(bitmapShader);
        final int w = b.getWidth(), h = b.getHeight();
        rect = new RectF(0, 0, w, h);
        this.borderRadius = borderRadius < 0 ? 0.15f * Math.min(w, h) : borderRadius;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(final Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, borderRadius, borderRadius, p);
    }
}
```

**CustomView.java**

```
public class CustomView extends ImageView {
    private View mMainContainer;
    private boolean mIsDirty=false;

    // TODO for each change of views/content, set mIsDirty to true and call invalidate

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (mIsDirty) {
            mIsDirty = false;
            drawContent();
            return;
        }
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

    /**
     * draws the view's content to a bitmap. code based on :
     * http://nadavfima.com/android-snippet-inflate-a-layout-draw-to-a-bitmap/
     */
    public static Bitmap drawToBitmap(final View viewToDrawFrom, final int width, final int height) {
        // Create a new bitmap and a new canvas using that bitmap
        final Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
        viewToDrawFrom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        // Supply measurements
        viewToDrawFrom.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getWidth(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(canvas.getHeight(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
        // Apply the measures so the layout would resize before drawing.
        viewToDrawFrom.layout(0, 0, viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredWidth(), viewToDrawFrom.getMeasuredHeight());
        // and now the bmp object will actually contain the requested layout
        canvas.drawBitmap(viewToDrawFrom.getDrawingCache(), 0, 0, new Paint());
        return bmp;
    }

    private void drawContent() {
        if (getMeasuredWidth() <= 0 || getMeasuredHeight() <= 0)
            return;
        final Bitmap bitmap = drawToBitmap(mMainContainer, getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredHeight());
        final RoundedCornersDrawable drawable = new RoundedCornersDrawable(getResources(), bitmap, 15);
        setImageDrawable(drawable);
    }

}
```

---

EDIT: found a nice alternative, based on [**"RoundKornersLayouts" library**](https://github.com/JcMinarro/RoundKornerLayouts). Have a class that will be used for all of the layout classes you wish to extend, to be rounded:

```
//based on https://github.com/JcMinarro/RoundKornerLayouts
class CanvasRounder(cornerRadius: Float, cornerStrokeColor: Int = 0, cornerStrokeWidth: Float = 0F) {
    private val path = android.graphics.Path()
    private lateinit var rectF: RectF
    private var strokePaint: Paint?
    var cornerRadius: Float = cornerRadius
        set(value) {
            field = value
            resetPath()
        }

    init {
        if (cornerStrokeWidth <= 0)
            strokePaint = null
        else {
            strokePaint = Paint()
            strokePaint!!.style = Paint.Style.STROKE
            strokePaint!!.isAntiAlias = true
            strokePaint!!.color = cornerStrokeColor
            strokePaint!!.strokeWidth = cornerStrokeWidth
        }
    }

    fun round(canvas: Canvas, drawFunction: (Canvas) -> Unit) {
        val save = canvas.save()
        canvas.clipPath(path)
        drawFunction(canvas)
        if (strokePaint != null)
            canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, strokePaint)
        canvas.restoreToCount(save)
    }

    fun updateSize(currentWidth: Int, currentHeight: Int) {
        rectF = android.graphics.RectF(0f, 0f, currentWidth.toFloat(), currentHeight.toFloat())
        resetPath()
    }

    private fun resetPath() {
        path.reset()
        path.addRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW)
        path.close()
    }

}
```

Then, in each of your customized layout classes, add code similar to this one:

```
class RoundedConstraintLayout : ConstraintLayout {
    private lateinit var canvasRounder: CanvasRounder

    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) {
        init(context, null, 0)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) {
        init(context, attrs, 0)
    }

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyle: Int) : super(context, attrs, defStyle) {
        init(context, attrs, defStyle)
    }

    private fun init(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?, defStyle: Int) {
        val array = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RoundedCornersView, 0, 0)
        val cornerRadius = array.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornersView_corner_radius, 0f)
        val cornerStrokeColor = array.getColor(R.styleable.RoundedCornersView_corner_stroke_color, 0)
        val cornerStrokeWidth = array.getDimension(R.styleable.RoundedCornersView_corner_stroke_width, 0f)
        array.recycle()
        canvasRounder = CanvasRounder(cornerRadius,cornerStrokeColor,cornerStrokeWidth)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            setLayerType(FrameLayout.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
        }
    }

    override fun onSizeChanged(currentWidth: Int, currentHeight: Int, oldWidth: Int, oldheight: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(currentWidth, currentHeight, oldWidth, oldheight)
        canvasRounder.updateSize(currentWidth, currentHeight)
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) = canvasRounder.round(canvas) { super.draw(canvas) }

    override fun dispatchDraw(canvas: Canvas) = canvasRounder.round(canvas) { super.dispatchDraw(canvas) }

}
```

If you wish to support attributes, use this as written on the library:

```
<resources>
  <declare-styleable name="RoundedCornersView">
      <attr name="corner_radius" format="dimension"/>
      <attr name="corner_stroke_width" format="dimension"/>
      <attr name="corner_stroke_color" format="color"/>
  </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

---

Another alternative, which might be easier for most uses: use MaterialCardView . It allows customizing the rounded corners, stroke color and width, and elevation.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:clipChildren="false" android:clipToPadding="false"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="100dp" android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp" app:cardElevation="8dp" app:strokeColor="#f00" app:strokeWidth="2dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:background="#0f0"/>

    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

And the result:

[image]

Do note that there is a slight artifacts issue at the edges of the stroke (leaves some pixels of the content there), if you use it. You can notice it if you zoom in. I've reported about this issue [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112064791).

EDIT: seems to be fixed, but not on the IDE. Reported [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139935302).

Comment: Thanks for assembling this awesome answer, It's got me moving in the right direction, but I could use some help with a very related problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25877515/appwidget-image-with-rounded-corners

Comment: This gives error as there is no default constructor available in ImageView.

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Instead of flat logic you went down and find an awesome solution. Also this solves problems you mentioned in comments to other answers. Thanks for your effort and maybe you can right a fully functional class and share it via github. I think it might help too many people.

Comment: @Senhor You think I should? I will think about it. For now, you can see the other repositories I've made, here: https://github.com/AndroidDeveloperLB?tab=repositories

Comment: As a big part of it done you can give it a try. Btw autofittextview looks really cool.

Comment: @Senhor Thank you. I tried making it easy to understand how it works, even though most of its code was not mine at all. It does have an issue though. Hope I will find the reason for it and fix it too.

Comment: How i can use that with `LinearLayout`?

Comment: @hema18 You can use any view you wish. Just set the mMainContainer to be the view that contains the others (LinearLayout in your case).

Answer (score 18):

**Step 1: Define bg_layout.xml in drawables folder, and put the below code in it.**

**Step 2: Add that bg_layout.xml as background to your layout, Done.**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="#EEEEEE"/> <!--your desired colour for solid-->

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#EEEEEE" /> <!--your desired colour for border-->

    <corners
        android:radius="50dp"/> <!--shape rounded value-->

</shape>
```

Answer (score 14):

If you would like to make your layout rounded, it is best to use the CardView, it provided many features to make the design beautiful.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
      <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight=".3"
                android:text="@string/quote_code"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_head_size" />
      </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

With this card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp", you can change the radius.

Answer (score 12):

Try this...

1.create **drawable xml**(custom_layout.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="#FF785C" />

<corners android:radius="10dp" />

</shape>
```

2.add your view background

```
android:background="@drawable/custom_layout"
```

Comment: Just as I wrote above of similar solution: This doesn't work. as you've set, it's the background, so the content overrides the rounded corners, and if you have content that draws on the corners, you won't see them being rounded.

Answer (score 10):

With the Material Components Library you can use the [**`MaterialShapeDrawable`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) to [draw custom shapes](https://github.com/material-components).

Just put the LinearLayout in your xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linear_rounded"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ..>

    <!-- content ..... -->

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in your code you can apply a `ShapeAppearanceModel`. Something like:

```
float radius = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.default_corner_radius);

LinearLayout linearLayout= findViewById(R.id.linear_rounded);
ShapeAppearanceModel shapeAppearanceModel = new ShapeAppearanceModel()
    .toBuilder()
    .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,radius)
    .build();

MaterialShapeDrawable shapeDrawable = new MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel);
//Fill the LinearLayout with your color
shapeDrawable.setFillColor(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this,R.color.secondaryLightColor));


ViewCompat.setBackground(linearLayout,shapeDrawable);
```

[image]

**Note::** it requires the version **1.1.0** of the material components library.

Comment: Here is my observation that can hopefully help somebody. If you set wrong radius for the above (excessively high, say 56 instead of 20, if control height is 40 for example), the above corners will display correct anyways, but only as of api 21. For api 19 they will be terribly messed up :) unless you enter correct radius.

Comment: @ror, I had the same behavior on API26. It turned out that I set `clipToOutline=true`. After removing clipToOutline everything came back to normal.

Answer (score 7):

The best and simplest method would be to make use of **card_background** drawable in your layout. This also follows Google's material design guidelines. Just include this in you LinearLayout:

```
android:background="@drawable/card_background"
```

Add this to your drawable directory and name it **card_background.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#BDBDBD"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item
        android:left="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
            <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 7):

Function for set corner radius programmatically

```
static void setCornerRadius(GradientDrawable drawable, float topLeft,
        float topRight, float bottomRight, float bottomLeft) {
    drawable.setCornerRadii(new float[] { topLeft, topLeft, topRight, topRight,
            bottomRight, bottomRight, bottomLeft, bottomLeft });
}

static void setCornerRadius(GradientDrawable drawable, float radius) {
    drawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
}
```

Using

```
GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = new GradientDrawable();
gradientDrawable.setColor(Color.GREEN);
setCornerRadius(gradientDrawable, 20f);
//or setCornerRadius(gradientDrawable, 20f, 40f, 60f, 80f); 

view.setBackground(gradientDrawable);
```

Answer (score 6):

Use CardView to get rounded edges for any layouts. 
Use **card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"** for cardview to get rounded layout edges.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">

      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
          <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:weightSum="1">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".3"
                    android:text="@string/quote_code"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_head_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".7"
                    android:text="@string/quote_details"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_head_size" />
            </LinearLayout>
       </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: CardView from support.v7 library, you can use from API7 or higher.

Answer (score 5):

A better way to do it would be:

**background_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:gravity="fill">
        <color android:color="@color/black"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:gravity="fill">
            <solid android:color="@color/white"/>
            <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
            <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

This will work below API 21 also, and give you something like this:

[image: Result]

---

If you are willing to make a little more effort more better control, then use `android.support.v7.widget.CardView` with its `cardCornerRadius` attribute (and set `elevation` attribute to `0dp` to get rid of any accompanying drop shadow with the cardView). Also, this will work from API level as low as 15.

Comment: If the content fits the background, it will override it. It doesn't really clip to the shape you've set.

Comment: You mean another view? Can you please update the code to show what you mean? The idea is that the rounded corners would not put black area. Around the corners, there should be transparent color.

Comment: Oh i get your question now. I guess for that, you can make do with a small fixed margin on your content

Comment: But then, the content won't be cut to the shape you choose, because fixed margins are rectangular, and not according to the shape you choose.

Answer (score 5):

Create your xml in drawable, `layout_background.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
      <solid android:color="@color/your_colour" />
      <stroke
            android:width="2dp"
            android:color="@color/your_colour" />
      <corners android:radius="10dp" />      
    </shape>
 <--width, color, radius should be as per your requirement-->
```

and then, add this in your `layout.xml`

```
 android:background="@drawable/layout_background"
```

Answer (score 5):

I've taken @gauravsapiens answer with my comments inside to give you a reasonable apprehension of what the parameters will effect.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <!-- Stroke around the background, width and color -->
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@color/drop_shadow"/>

    <!-- The corners of the shape -->
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>

    <!-- Padding for the background, e.g the Text inside a TextView will be 
    located differently -->
    <padding android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" 
             android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" />

</shape>
```

If you're just looking to create a shape that rounds the corners, removing the padding and the stroke will do. If you remove the solid as well you will, in effect, have created rounded corners on a transparent background.

For the sake of being lazy I have created a shape underneath, which is just a solid white background with rounded corners - enjoy! :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background color -->
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />

    <!-- The corners of the shape -->
    <corners android:radius="4dp"/>

</shape>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="3dip" android:top="3dip" android:right="3dip" android:bottom="3dip" />
</shape>
```

@David, just put padding same value as stroke, so border can be visible, regardeless image size

Answer (score 4):

```
 <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp"
android:shape="rectangle">

<solid android:color="@color/header" />

<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:topLeftRadius="@dimen/_5sdp"
    android:topRightRadius="@dimen/_5sdp" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If what you want is just a **simple rounded rectangle**, cut the long story short.

```
float r=8;
ShapeDrawable shape = 
   new ShapeDrawable (new RoundRectShape(new float[] { r, r, r, r, r, r, r, r },null,null));
shape.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
view.setBackground(shape);
```

[image: android rounded rectangle shape]

- *The first two floats are for the top-left corner (remaining pairs correspond clockwise).*

for more details read [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57974149/7756492)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a bit late to the party, but this is still a problem. So I wrote a set of OutlineProviders and BindingAdapters for data binding that enables you to clip corners from xml.

> NOTE: Clipping with outline does not support corners to be different sizes!

I wrote a detailed response with code on [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959103/android-how-to-clip-only-top-rounded-corners/67582960#67582960)

What you will get with code + binding adapter:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    clipRadius="@{@dimen/some_radius}"
    clipBottomLeft="@{@dimen/some_radius}"
    clipBottomRight="@{@dimen/some_radius}"
    clipTopLeft="@{@dimen/some_radius}"
    clipTopRight="@{@dimen/some_radius}"
    clipCircle="@{@bool/clip}"
```

This enables you to clip the view to a circle, round all corners, round corners in one direction (left, top, right, bottom) or single corners.

Comment: If you just want a rounded background this is overkill, you're better off with drawable xml. But if you want to round off the corners of a layout without say an image sticking out this is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a custom view, like this [RoundAppBar](https://github.com/rezaiyan/Podcast/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/hezaro/wall/utils/HAppBarLayout.kt) and [RoundBottomAppBar](https://github.com/rezaiyan/Podcast/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/hezaro/wall/utils/HBottomAppBar.kt).
Here a `path` is used to `clipPath` the canvas.

[image: Round Corner View]