# How would you create a popover view in Android, like Facebook Comments?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I was wondering if anyone knows how to create a Facebook-like popover view like in the Facebook Android app for comments.

This is what I mean:

[image]

Along with the handle that you can drag to dismiss it, is it a native Android UI control or has Facebook implemented this themselves?

Comment: I am facing similar problem, creating comments detail view and drag right or down to dismiss and open likes view over comments view. Can you share your code how you implemented it by views and view group as it seems it can not be achieved by dialog or popup.

Comment: That's an interesting conversation you chose to screencap.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The best way to create similar `popover view` is by using [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), since you can place the `PopUpWindow` on any of the specific view position (or on center/top/bottom of screen). You can also achieve same UI with `DialogFragment` , but you cannot position at specific view location.

I have a complete working code here https://gist.github.com/libinbensin/67fcc43a7344758390c3

*Step 1:* Create your custom layout , for e.g., as Facebook its has a `Header TextView` with a `ListView` and `EditText`.

*Step 2:* Set the layout to the `PopupWindow`

*Inflate the layout to set*

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
final View inflatedView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fb_popup_layout, null,false);
```

This `Layout` has a `ListView` ,so find the `ListView` in the layout and fill the data . you can have your own view here

```
ListView listView = (ListView)inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.commentsListView);
listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(TryMeActivity.this,
        R.layout.fb_comments_list_item, android.R.id.text1,contactsList));
```

Now, create an instance of `PopupWindow` with specific height and width. I prefer to set the size depends on the device.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);

popWindow = new PopupWindow(inflatedView, size.x - 50,size.y - 500, true );
```

Set the `focusability` of the popup window.

```
popWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

Make it outside touchable `to dismiss the popup window when touched outside` the popup area

```
popWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Now, set a background to the `PopupWindow` with a drawable. The drawable has `rectangle shape` with `corner radius`.

```
  popWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.fb_popup_bg));
```

Finally. show the `PopupWindow` at required location. I made it show at `bottom` of the screen with some `X and Y position`

```
popWindow.showAtLocation(v, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,150);  // 0 - X postion and 150 - Y position
```

You can also set an `Animation` to use when the `PopUpWindow` appears and disappears

```
popWindow.setAnimationStyle(R.anim.animation); // call this before showing the popup
```

[image]

Comment: Works great! You got me in the right direction - although I did end up using a View and ViewGroup instead of a PopupWindow in the end,

Comment: Excellent example, ty. One quick Q, if I wanted to make some type of line or connector to the anchor, how would you suggest doing that? (See my image here for a visual example of the top-right corner connecting to the anchor - http://i422.photobucket.com/albums/pp308/P_G_Mac/connected%20example.png )

Comment: @Silmarilos, did you figure out a way?

Comment: @Faser sadly no. I ended up just doing a manual marginTop method, but it does not expand well at all on tablets :(

Answer (score 7):

**Edit:**

Actually, even though I used a DialogFragment, I'm quite certain their popup does not use a DialogFragment (or even a Dialog at all!). The reason for this is the resizing feature. If that is something you want, then you can't use a DialogFragment. You would have to just add a new view to your layout. It looks like facebook also has another view that sits between your wall and the fake popup that is slightly translucent and listens for clicks in order to dismiss the view. Something like this would take some actual effort and time to build, so I won't make this one for you. Let me know if you have any questions about it though, I can probably guide you to the solution you are after.

**Original:**

I wrote the popup for you:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            F1.newInstance().show(getFragmentManager(), null);
        }
    }

    public static class F1 extends DialogFragment {

        public static F1 newInstance() {
            F1 f1 = new F1();
            f1.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog);
            return f1;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Remove the default background
            getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

            // Inflate the new view with margins and background
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, container, false);

            // Set up a click listener to dismiss the popup if they click outside
            // of the background view
            v.findViewById(R.id.popup_root).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dismiss();
                }
            });

            return v;
        }
    }
}
```

popup_layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/popup_root">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="72dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:background="@drawable/dialog_background">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:text="Content goes here!" />

    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

And dialog_background.xml (goes into res/drawable):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#FFF" />
    <corners android:topLeftRadius="20dp" android:topRightRadius="20dp"
         android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp" android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"/>
    <stroke android:color="#7F7F7F" android:width="1dp" />
</shape>
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

Just add your view content and you're good to go!

Comment: This is the best answer so far, but I just wanted to ask, is there a way to make the Dialog not cover the ActionBar? Specifically, is there a way for the overlay part to only cover the Fragment it is displayed in?

Comment: You can't, not with Dialogs. I think you would just have to "fake" a dialog by adding a normal fragment with a translucent background to the top of your FrameLayout that sits underneath the ActionBar. When the user clicks outside, just remove the Fragment from the layout. You have more flexibility that way too, you can control the size of the view etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a PopupWindow to do that. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html

Of course you'll need to style it and fill in the popup's contents on your own. You can get some styling ideas from [How to make layout with rounded corners..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a custom component built by Facebook. It is not a standard Android component. You can try implementing it by deriving from the Dialog Fragment.

Comment: Are you sure its Dialog Fragment? It seems a bit too complex to have been derived from just a Dialog Fragment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like it would be easiest to just use a Fragment with a transparent (or in this case translucent) background.