# Is there a way to show an Android dialog without graying out the back drop?

Tags: android

I want to pop open a DatePickerDialog in a certain screen, but I am required to not grey out the rest of the screen (the view behind the dialog) when the DatePickerDialog window opens. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean " grey out the rest of the screen "

Comment: Normally when a Dialog is opened, it appears on top of the screen that it was originated from, and everything behind it gets darker to create focus on the dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You probably would want to create your own custom dialog.  You can extend `DialogFramgent` and change it accordingly.

See the Android doc [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout) for a great example.

Or, use `PopupWindow` if you want a popover dialog with control of the background, see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23464232/how-would-you-create-a-popover-view-in-android-like-facebook-comments).

Comment: I've seen that doc, but it doesn't say anything about controlling and UI aspects OUTSIDE of the dialog itself. Do you know how I can modify the area outside of the dialog?

Comment: Please see my updated answer.  Scroll down to the picture in the answer and you will see that the background is not greyed out.