# Android Compile Error, cannot find 'corners' attribute

Tags: android, xml, rounded-corners

I cannot figure out why my Android Studio is giving me this error when I am trying to make my `FrameLayout` have rounded edges. This is the exact error it gives me "Error:(162) No resource identifier found for attribute 'corners' in package 'android'", I have rebuilt my project to see if that was the problem but fortunately it wasn't, can someone explain. I am running version 0.8 Android Studio and my Lowest SDK Version is API 13.

The XML layout file that gives me the error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke android:color="#000000" android:width="1dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Update**
I no longer get the 'corners' attribute error.
I recreated the file by deleting it and creating a new `XML` file, but when I try to apply this layout to my FrameLayout I get this error "Error:(126, 15) error: method setBackground in class View cannot be applied to given types;

required: Drawable

found: int

reason: actual argument int cannot be converted to Drawable by method invocation conversion"

Comment: please provide more code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's not a layout; it's a shape drawable. ensure it is located in "res/drawable" not "res/layout".

Comment: It is in drawable, and I'm applying it to a FrameLayout through myLayout.setBackground(R.drawable.roundcorners);

Comment: actually, looking at the error message, it's complaining about a `corners` _attribute_ but your code sample only has a `<corners>` _element_. assuming you didn't misquote the error or the xml, i can only suggest cleaning/rebuilding your project.

Comment: setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myshape);

Comment: Thank you so much for that comment. Everything is fixed

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess: maybe because you are specifying shape as rectangle there is a problem with corners?

Check this answer: [How to make layout with rounded corners..?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: That's where I got the code from, I'll do what it says in the answer and report back with what happens