# Rectangle's corner border radius is not perfect (Android Shape)

Tags: android, xml, android-xml, shapes

I tried to create a rectangle shape with corner radius and border on android. I almost made it, just a little problem that i cant solve until now :

[image]

The border already has some radius on its corner, but the inner rectangle does NOT (please see the red mark on the image).

This is my code :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
    <stroke  android:width="3dp" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

I use this shape by using `android:src` on the `ImageView`.

This is how i use the shape :

```
<ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/rectangle"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

And this is how i maintain the shape's size (on my adapter) :

```
holder.answer.setBackgroundColor(getItem(position).getColor());
holder.answer.getLayoutParams().width = (int) GlobalUtil.size;
holder.answer.getLayoutParams().height = (int) GlobalUtil.size;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(holder.answer.getLayoutParams());
lp.setMargins(0, (int) GlobalUtil.gapGrid, 0, (int) GlobalUtil.gapGrid);
holder.answer.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Please kindly help me out, Thanks.

Comment: can you post the xml where you used this.

Comment: Have you tried this? [How to make layout with rounded corners..?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16161493/761668

Comment: @BlazeTama where does the green backgroudn coming from?? and also the nunber 1?

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin the green background and text is from the java code. Do you need it?

Comment: @BlazeTama if you may, can you post it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin please kindly see my edited question. Sorry it might be a little hard to understand because i count the size manually

Comment: @BlazeTama, were u able to resolve the issue, mate as i am also facing the same issue, if yes then please share

Answer (score 3):

Use `android:background` instead of `android:src` because right now it is applying scaling according to density.

**EDIT:**

rectangle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<stroke  android:width="3dp" android:color="#00FF00" />
```

ImageView

```
<ImageView
    android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Java code:

```
//holder.answer.setBackgroundColor(getItem(position).getColor());
holder.answer.getLayoutParams().width = (int) GlobalUtil.size;
holder.answer.getLayoutParams().height = (int) GlobalUtil.size;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(holder.answer.getLayoutParams());
lp.setMargins(0, (int) GlobalUtil.gapGrid, 0, (int) GlobalUtil.gapGrid);
holder.answer.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. If i change it to be the background, the border and radius is disappear hence it just showing a normal rectangle. Please see my edited question for more information.

Comment: @BlazeTama: it is not disappeared. zoom your layout and checkout. it is having width of 3dp so it will be very thin.If you want to maintain the width properly, I would suggest you to use 9patch image instead of shape drawable.

Comment: I have zoomed it and change the width..its disappeared. Please kindly see my edited question, Thanks

Comment: @BlazeTama: you can not set background from both, xml and java. it will override old one. try my edited answer and if it shows you some kind of green background with rectangle having radius then I hope you will understand what was going wrong.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I need to set the color manually in Java. What should i do? Thanks a lot

Comment: @BlazeTama: Use 9Patch image.

Comment: Sorry but i need to set the random color to the rectangle. Can i accomplish that with the 9Patch? Thanks

Comment: @BlazeTama: use 9patch image for only in background. u can still use colors in java code.