# Element shape doesn't have required attribute android:layout_height

Tags: android, xml

I'm using a shape element to put as the background of a view, doing as this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners/16161493#16161493). I'm using Android Studio and it tells me that...

`Element shape doesn't have required attribute android:layout_height`

`Element shape doesn't have required attribute android:layout_width`

The code is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<solid android:color="@color/darkBrown"/>
<stroke android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<corners android:radius="10dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:bottom="0dip"/>

</shape>
```

So basically my question: why do I get this error if shapes technically don't need these attributes? How can I tell android to stop marking it as an error or how can I avoid it?

Thank you.

SOLVED: The reason was because it wasn't inside the `drawable` folder.

EDIT: Yes I'm aware the stroke part is incorrect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The reason the error was shown is because it wasn't inside the `drawable` folder. (It moved automatically to `layout` when I renamed the `drawable` folder after a typo.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what a shape should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
<corners
    android:radius="14dp"
    />
<solid
    android:color="#ADD8E6"
    />
<padding
    android:left="0dp"
    android:top="0dp"
    android:right="0dp"
    android:bottom="0dp"
    />
<size
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="60dp"
    />
<stroke
    android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#ADD8E6"
    />

</shape>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I still can't get rid of the red! Maybe it's an Android Studio thing? ![Screenie here](http://i.gyazo.com/c7d53f389ae1f3c503b10b253afb5ab0.png)

EDIT: Okay my bad, for some reason the layout_bg.xml moved to layout when I renamed the drawable folder!

Answer (score 0):

You drawable XML is not correct in the first place. You cannot just use attributes you like and expect it work, for example your `<stroke>` has `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` which makes no sense for `<stroke>` and is not supported. It also `android:width` though, but this is different `width` and got NOTHING in common with `layout_width`. Docs [are here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) and include all attributes supported.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the error, because I still get it even after using technically correct attributes for width and height (copied the code provided by the answer above you).

Answer (score 0):

You drawable XML is not correct in the first place. You cannot just use attributes you like and expect it work, for example your  has android:layout_width and android:layout_height which makes no sense for  and is not supported. It also android:width though, but this is different width and got NOTHING in common with layout_width. Docs are here and include all attributes supported.

Comment: digging up thread from 2015 that is already answered..

Comment: @Bartosz  I'm beginner here and i'm just learning or practice to giving or post answers in this section so please do not take it personally