# Round selected corner of linear layout

Tags: android, xml, rounded-corners, cornerradius

Basically I have a linear layout with a custom background drawable in order to round the corner. I only want to round the bottom left and bottom right corner.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        <solid android:color="#000000" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:left="5dp" android:right="5dp" android:bottom="5dp">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:topLeftRadius="0.01dp" android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp" android:bottomRightRadius="5dp" android:topRightRadius="0.01dp" />
        <solid android:color="@color/app" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

However, this xml doesn't work. I still get all corner rounded even though I have set an extremely small values for top left and right corner radius.  Can anyone help me?

[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VH8JJ.png)

Comment: You are using **2** items in  alayerlist. The first one has all the corners set to `5dp`

Comment: @Kelok, Can you please try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners/16161658#16161658 one ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dip"
        android:color="#92d050" />

    <corners 
        android:bottomLeftRadius="10dip" 
        android:bottomRightRadius="10dip" 
        android:topLeftRadius="0dip"
        android:topRightRadius="0dip"/>

    <padding
        android:bottom="0dip"
        android:left="0dip"
        android:right="0dip"
        android:top="0dip" />

</shape>
```