# Android custom rectangle

Tags: android, android-custom-view, shapes, rectangles, android-cardview

In my app i need to create cardview with curved top and bottom lines, like this:

[image]

I tried to search answer on stackoverflow and google but i haven't found anything. Also i tried to make it via xml, but i couldn't.
Can anyone help me with this? I can't use it like image background because i need to change background color when i click on card and i have a lot of such card in my recyclerview and a lot of different colors for every card.
Thx.

Comment: for cardView you need to add (card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp") to the cards layout -- http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom shape a la [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) as the background of the view. **edit** see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: I know how to make rounded corners, but don't understand how to make top and bottoms lines like on imageview.

Comment: I would say those are most likely PNGs.