# Diagonal Cut ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, diagonal

How can I achieve the corner edges on the image on the bottom right and left of the image? Not the rounded corners this i already achieve but the diagonal cut at the bottom left and right of the image I am only talking about the above image not the white one. I tried some libraries but didn't work. The part that i want to achieve is in black.I load the image using glide. Thanks.

Here is the image.

[image]

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/voucher_background" />

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_header_panel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_heightPercent="28.18%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="2.14%">

            <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_header"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
                    android:contentDescription="@null" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_logo"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
                    app:layout_aspectRatio="178%"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:contentDescription="@null"/>

            </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_price_label"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="30dp"
                    android:textColor="@color/promos_vouchers_price_label_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/promos_vouchers_price_label_text_size"
                    tools:text="até" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_price_value"
                    android:layout_width="65dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="-40dp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/promos_vouchers_price_value_text_color"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/promos_vouchers_price_value_text_size"
                    tools:text="€4" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/promos_vouchers_header_panel"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="12dp"
            app:layout_heightPercent="40.36%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="7.13%">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:maxLines="7"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/promos_vouchers_description_main_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/promos_voucher_description_text_size"
                android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_final_date"
                tools:text="Desconto de 2 cêntimos por lite em combústível evologic, é válido para qualquer posto com um limite mínimo de 1l e máximo de 50l." />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_final_date"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/promos_vouchers_invisible_placeholder"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:textColor="@color/promos_vouchers_description_alt_text_color"
                android:textSize="@dimen/promos_voucher_options_text_size"
                tools:text="Data de Fim: 09-10-2015" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_invisible_placeholder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:src="@drawable/voucher_invisible_placeholder" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_final_date"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_info"  />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_button"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="26dp"
            android:paddingStart="24dp"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:paddingEnd="24dp"
            android:text="@string/promo_vouchers_use_cupon"
            app:layout_heightPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginBottomPercent="12.19%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="7.13%"
            style="@style/ActiveButton"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_below="@+id/promos_vouchers_description_container"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


        <!--<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_bar_code"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/promos_vouchers_description_container"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            app:layout_heightPercent="17.13%"
            app:layout_marginBottomPercent="12.19%"
            app:layout_marginLeftPercent="7.13%"
            app:layout_marginRightPercent="7.13%" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_bar_code_number"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/promos_vouchers_bar_code"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_background_color"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:letterSpacing="0.2"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_padding"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_padding"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_padding"
            android:textSize="@dimen/promos_voucher_bar_code_text_size"
            app:layout_marginBottomPercent="0%"
            tools:text="0006005316002094" />
        <include
            android:id="@+id/promos_vouchers_bar_code_loading"
            layout="@layout/common_loading_progressbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/promos_vouchers_description_container"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />!-->

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And the image is dynamically so i am using glide to load it.

```
 Glide.with(context)
                .load(banner.getBannerCover() != null ? banner.getBannerCover().getImage() : null)
                .bitmapTransform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(context, context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.voucher_rounder_corner_radius), 0, RoundedCornersTransformation.CornerType.TOP))
                .animate(R.anim.fade_in)
                .into((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.promos_vouchers_header))
```

Comment: Show me your current `xml` or image code so that I can write an answer edit your question by adding those. I dont have an idea on how much you have tried so far.

Comment: Create image in photoshop and put it as the resource for an `ImageView`. This'll be the best  way as I don't think you want to use those corners for clicking.

Comment: I posted now my xml @Xenolion. Thanks.

Comment: @LalitSinghFauzdar yes i can do that but dont you think it won´t work because the top image view is loaded dynamically? That cut has to do with this image too.

Comment: Have you found any solution for cutting corners?

Answer (score 0):

Those corner edges are achieved by using corner edges selectors. Check out this link for corner edges: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Karthik mas I dont want to achieve the rounded corners. This I already have. I want that diagonal cut on the bottom left and right of the image. Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.. Follow below steps

1. Inside your drawable folder create one `xml` called `shape.xml` Put below code in your file.

   ```
       <padding android:left="5dp"
           android:top="5dp"
           android:right="5dp"
           android:bottom="5dp"
           />

       <corners 
              android:bottomRightRadius="17dp" 
              android:bottomLeftRadius="17dp"
              android:topLeftRadius="17dp" 
              android:topRightRadius="17dp"
           />
   ```

   Add this code under `<shape>` tag.
2. Add below line to your `Imageview` as an `xml` attribute.

   ```
   android:background="@drawable/shape"
   ```

Output will look like..

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you response but i dont want to achieve the rounded corners. This I already have. What i want is to achieve that cut on the bottom left and right of the image, not the rounded corners. What i want I put a black circle on that. Thanks.