# How to cut the corners of a background?

Tags: android, xml

I want to cut the white portion of the dialog form the following:
Any help would be appreciated. Thanx in advance

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPbiw.png

Comment: Have you tried anything ??

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#2029afcb"/>
    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <corners android:radius="15dp"        />
    <size android:width="280dp" android:height="200dp"/>
</shape>

Comment: Show your custom `AlertDialog` layout.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners

Comment: This is not a duplicate of something that can be solved with an ImageView. The underlaying dialog has its background set to a white rounded rectangle. A good answer will try to replace that dialog background.

Answer (score 1):

Create a xml in drawable , say dialog_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <solid
    android:color="@color/white"/>
<corners
    android:radius="30dp" />
<padding
    android:left="10dp"
    android:top="10dp"
    android:right="10dp"
    android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>
```

set it as the background in your layout xml

```
android:background="@drawable/dialog_bg"
```

set the background of your dialog to transparent

```
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Or add this try:

```
 dialog.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
```

Also you can set own style:

```
 /* theme is optional, I am using leanback... */
 setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.AppTheme_Leanback);
```

Or:

```
<style name="Custom.Dialog" parent="android:Theme.DeviceDefault.Dialog.NoActionBar.MinWidth" >
      <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
      <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
 </style>
```

Comment: no luck..giving transparent dialog which is not needed

Comment: As a variant you can use picture.png with round corners as a dialog’s background.

Answer (score 1):

use cardView has its has properties related to rounded corners and elevation

Answer (score 0):

add it like this to your layout as background

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rectangle"
     </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is giving sharp corners, but I want rounded corners

Comment: in which layout are you applying this xml?

Comment: still not there

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView".../>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn1".../>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dialog_btn2"... />
</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

Comment: <corners android:radius="15dp" /> remove this line from your `layout_background` file and check