# clipToOutline with cornerRadii with background

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, background

Sometimes in my practice I want to round view's background corners.
Usually i use something like this (***@drawable/bg_rounded***)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="16dp"/>
</shape>
```

But sometimes i need to round only one angle and do this **programmatically**

I create a test project to show the problem.
***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

MainActivity class may be like

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val container = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.container)
        container.clipToOutline = true
        val background: GradientDrawable =
            container.background.mutate() as? GradientDrawable ?: return
        background.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(
            20F, 20F, 20F, 20F,
            20F, 20F, 20F, 20F
        )
    }
}
```

but unexpected behavior happens - corners are not rounded
[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFEt0.png)

if i use ***background.cornerRadius*** it works predictable

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val container = findViewById<FrameLayout>(R.id.container)
        container.clipToOutline = true
        val background: GradientDrawable =
            container.background.mutate() as? GradientDrawable ?: return
        background.cornerRadius = 20F
//        background.cornerRadii = floatArrayOf(
//            20F, 20F, 20F, 20F,
//            20F, 20F, 20F, 20F
//        )
    }
}
```

[click to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vvwF.png)

**So my question is: what should I use to achieve dynamic adjustment of different radius of corners**

Comment: You can also use the MaterialShapeDrawable as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161448/how-to-make-layout-with-rounded-corners/59454788#59454788)

Comment: thank you for answer. But it's not work for me.
if i use setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED,40F) it works
if i want to round only one corner - it doesn't works.
i mean corner sets correctly, but child view doesn't cuts with clipToOutline = true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if i use background.cornerRadius it works predictable

It is because `clipping` only supports rectangle, circle, or round rect.

When you use `background.cornerRadius` it uses `RoundRect` to draw, but when you use `background.cornerRadii` it uses `Path` to draw, and path clipping is not supported until `API 33`. [Check outline documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Outline#canClip())

You cannot use variable corners radius, but you can do a workaround to keep rounded corners at desired positions by using `ViewOutlineProvider` and `RoundRect` to draw the `outline`. You can read more detailed answers about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55959103/android-how-to-clip-only-top-rounded-corners).