# Width and Height must be > 0

Tags: java, android-studio, exception, bitmap, android-constraintlayout

I AM GETTING THIS RENDER PROBLEM WHILE BUILDING PROJECT.
my project getting this error cause I used a rounded corner for one of my constrain layout, I clear don't know if this is by it, But I think this because of that reason.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1033)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:1000)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:950)
    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:911)
    at android.view.shadow.TriangleBuffer.setSize(TriangleBuffer.java:55)
    at android.view.shadow.AmbientShadowBitmapGenerator.<init>(AmbientShadowBitmapGenerator.java:43)
    at android.view.shadow.HighQualityShadowPainter.paintAmbientShadow(HighQualityShadowPainter.java:101)
    at android.view.shadow.HighQualityShadowPainter.paintRectShadow(HighQualityShadowPainter.java:66)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawShadow(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:90)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:62)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20077)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:67)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:67)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.dispatchDraw(ConstraintLayout.java:2023)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20077)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:67)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20075)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19849)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:67)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4333)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4112)
    at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:20210)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:20177)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:404)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.renderAndBuildResult(RenderSessionImpl.java:556)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.render(RenderSessionImpl.java:425)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.BridgeRenderSession.render(BridgeRenderSession.java:120)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:151)
    at com.android.ide.common.rendering.api.RenderSession.render(RenderSession.java:133)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$null$8(RenderTask.java:755)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

This is my Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.impwala">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/something"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/something_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".BEE"></activity>
        <activity android:name=".Physics1" />
        <activity android:name=".chemistry1" />
        <activity android:name=".Math1" />
        <activity android:name=".Main3Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my XML file where I am getting error, I think something went wrong when I use a rounded corner layout for one constrain layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient"

    tools:context=".Main2Activity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <!--suppress AndroidUnknownAttribute -->
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/bioconstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="35sp"
            android:background="@drawable/layout_bg"
            android:clipToOutline="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/biotextview2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/biotextview2">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/bioimageView2"
                android:layout_width="82dp"
                android:layout_height="84dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="4dp"
                tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/biotextview"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="166dp"
                android:layout_height="51dp"
                android:text="Biology"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/biotextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.347" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/biotextview2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="43dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                android:text="Available Now"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/bioarrowBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/bioimageView2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bioarrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:text="OPEN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/biotextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/mathconstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="35sp"
            android:background="#fffff0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="35dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mathimageView2"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
                android:contentDescription="TODO" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mathtextview"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="Math"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mathtextview2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:text="Coming Soon"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/matharrowBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mathimageView2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/matharrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:text="OPEN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mathtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/PhysicsconstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="35sp"
            android:background="#fffff0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Physicstextview2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Physicstextview2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/PhysicsimageView2"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Physicstextview2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Physicstextview2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Physicstextview2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Physicstextview"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="Physics"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Physicstextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Physicstextview2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:text="Coming Soon"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/PhysicsarrowBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/PhysicsimageView2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/PhysicsarrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:text="OPEN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Physicstextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/ChemconstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="35sp"
            android:background="#fffff0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Chemtextview2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Chemtextview2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ChemimageView2"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Chemtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Chemtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Chemtextview2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Chemtextview"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="Chemestry"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Chemtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Chemtextview2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:text="Coming Soon"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ChemarrowBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ChemimageView2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ChemarrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:text="OPEN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Chemtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

            android:id="@+id/EnglishconstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="35sp"
            android:background="#fffff0"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Englishtextview2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Englishtextview2">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/EnglishimageView2"
                android:layout_width="92dp"
                android:layout_height="92dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="23dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/twealth"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/Englishtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/Englishtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Englishtextview2" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Englishtextview"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="196dp"
                android:layout_height="49dp"
                android:text="English"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="25sp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/Englishtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.4" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/Englishtextview2"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="46dp"
                android:text="Coming Soon"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/EnglisharrowBtn"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/EnglishimageView2" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/EnglisharrowBtn"
                android:layout_width="67dp"
                android:layout_height="69dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
                android:text="OPEN"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/Englishtextview2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <!-- <Space
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="40dp"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/sem1"
             android:layout_width="230dp"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@drawable/gradient"
             android:text="@string/first_semester"
             android:textAllCaps="true" />

         <Space
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="15dp"
             android:layout_weight="1" />

         <Button
             android:id="@+id/sem2"
             android:layout_height="60dp"
             android:layout_width="230dp"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
             android:background="@drawable/gradient"
             android:text="@string/second_semester" />

         <Space
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="15dp"
             android:layout_weight="1" />-->


    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is layout_bg file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#fffff0"/>
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#f1f1f1" />
    <corners android:radius="60dp"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Hello, you have an error that _both_ width and height must be greater than 0 and you have such setting `android:layout_width="0dp"` - most likely this is the reason

Comment: Yeah specifically That solved it . But after that I am getting this error. AAPT: error: attribute android:clipToOutline not found.

Comment: Have you checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30692236/13279831)?  Summary: the XML attribute `clipToOutline` is not recognized, but it can be set in Java code.