# Textview design in android

Tags: android, android-layout, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, material-components

How can I make my text view in android to look like the one in image below

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16161493/4158832

Answer (score 1):

Use a **`TextInputLayout`**

```
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            app:boxBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:placeholderText="Name"
            app:hintEnabled="false">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can apply a **`MaterialShapeDrawable`** to your **`EditText`** (or `TextView`).
Define in your layout:

```
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:id="@+id/edittext"
            android:paddingStart="4dp"
            android:hint="Name"/>
```

Then:

```
    val radius = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.cornerSize8)

    val textView: EditText = findViewById(R.id.edittext)
    val shapeAppearanceModel = ShapeAppearanceModel()
        .toBuilder()
        .setAllCorners(CornerFamily.ROUNDED, radius)
        .build()

    val shapeDrawable = MaterialShapeDrawable(shapeAppearanceModel)
    shapeDrawable.fillColor = AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(this,R.color.white)
    ViewCompat.setBackground(textView, shapeDrawable)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's quite easy, you just need to set background drawable

textview_background.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/white" />
</shape>
```

TextView:

```xml
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/textview_background"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply Create a EditText in your Layout or a TextView with inputtype="Whatever you want"

like this

```
<EditText
     android:id="@+id/plain_text_input"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:inputType="text"
     android:text="First Name"
     android:background="@drawable/textbackground"
/>
```

and in drawable create textbackground.xml

drawable/textbackground.xml --

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
       <shape android:shape="rectangle">
           <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
           <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Hope it Works