# how to draw pic to Closed curve area

Tags: android

hollo,i want to draw a part of a image to a Closed curve,in the  onDraw(Canvas canvas)
i have use  the follow code draw a Closed curve
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    paint.setAlpha(80);
    canvas.drawPath(turnpage.mPath3, paint); 
  my question is that how to draw a part of a image to the Closed area.In other words,i want to know how to filling the close area  by using a any part of a image. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use xfer modes. Here is my example where a circle is used to punch though an image, you just need to reverse the logic by using a differnt Xfer mode: [Make certain area of bitmap transparent on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch/5439357#5439357)

Another example which place an image into a rounded rectangle: Look for the answer which is using Xfer modes. [How should I give images rounded corners in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705239/how-should-i-give-images-rounded-corners-in-android)

All xfer modes are demonstrated in Api Demos apllication which comes with Android SDK. In your Exclipse create a new Android project and select "Create project from existing sample". Choose target android version and then ApiDemos. Run the app and go to graphics then Xfermodes.