# Android: clip image to shape

Tags: android, image, graphics, shapes, clip

(Sorry for my bad english)
I have two pictures. One picture is colorful and big. On the other picture shows a black figure arbitrary shape (like a cross or a star or a piece of the classic puzzle) on a transparent background.
I want to put the second picture on the first picture and replace the black with part of the first image. Then i need to save the second image in a new file.

Thank you.
Max.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/221830/set-bufferedimage-alpha-mask-in-java/221990#221990

Answer (score 1):

You can get this by using a library and a single line code.
Please try this, hope you will get a better solution.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.mafstech.libs:mafs-image-shape:1.0.4'   
}
```

And this line is your main code

```
Shaper.shape(context, R.drawable.your_original_image_which_will_be_displayed, R.drawable.shaped_image__your_original_image_will_get_this_images_shape, imageView, height, weight);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use xfer modes, unless you are preaperd to create Paths and then clip canvas.

Check my answer here: [how to draw pic to Closed curve area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5768426/how-to-draw-pic-to-closed-curve-area)

Follow the links for examples...