# Codename One - How to check BubbleTransition support

Tags: java, crash, codenameone

*BubbleTransition* on some old devices (*4.0.4 and lower*) immediately crashes application with `UnsupportedOperationException` (viewed trace via *Android Studio*).

Stack trace guided me to some image clipping method.

**How to check if clipping is supported on current platform to avoid crashes?**

Stack trace

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                  at android.view.GLES20Canvas.clipPath(GLES20Canvas.java:417)
                  at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidGraphics.setClipRaw(AndroidGraphics.java:1368)
                  at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView$AsyncOp.executeWithClip(AndroidAsyncView.java:144)
                  at com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidAsyncView.dispatchDraw(AndroidAsyncView.java:229)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10519)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2701)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10484)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2701)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10484)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2701)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10484)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2701)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10484)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2701)
                  at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10484)
                  at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:851)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1910)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
                  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

### Possible CN1 implementation fix

Possibly could be fixed by a check for the Android API level and below API 18 disable hardware acceleration with

```
setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

The problem is related to **forced hardware acceleration** on **ICS** devices.
But it is related to CN1 implementation, so there is nothing I can do with it.

Comment: Please check the page How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace, copy and paste it from Android Studio into the question (you can edit it) and then comment here so I will get a notification that you edited the question.

Comment: @ShaiAlmog added stack trace and found possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676059/android-unsupportedoperationexception-at-canvas-clippath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks we'll fix it for the next update coming on Friday February 3rd 2017. The fix will disable shaped clipping for the older devices which will force the bubble transition into compatibility mode.

The reason for this approach is that we wouldn't want the whole device to slow down because of one missing feature, I'd rather avoid shape clipping than have performance suffer.

Comment: "...you can turn off hardware acceleration for just the affected portion of your application by calling `setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)`
This way, you can still take advantage of hardware acceleration everywhere else..."

Source: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/hardware-accel.html

Comment: This isn't applicable in our case