# NullPointerException in android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas

Tags: android

I'm seeing NullPointerException crash reports in android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawPatch()

The Android source is here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/view/GLES20RecordingCanvas.java

Seems to be crashing at line 97 for 4.0.x only, when the activity has hardware acceleration on.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.view.GLES20RecordingCanvas.drawPatch(GLES20RecordingCanvas.java:97)
at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:125)
at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:189)
at android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.drawThumb(ScrollBarDrawable.java:178)
at android.widget.ScrollBarDrawable.draw(ScrollBarDrawable.java:137)
at android.view.View.onDrawVerticalScrollBar(View.java:9532)
at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:9476)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11091)
at android.widget.AbsListView.draw(AbsListView.java:3428)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10455)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2858)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2497)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:11067)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10455)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:2605)
at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:10418)
at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:879)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:1955)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1661)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there an easy fix for this, or do I need to just turn off hardware acceleration for the affected activity?

Comment: There's no relevant code - this happens when I'm trying to resume a backgrounded activity on a 4.0.x device. You can see in the crash, it looks like it crashes trying to draw the ListView scroll thumb.

Comment: Did you try my answer? Let me know if it helped you, please.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to solve this. It boils down to **disabling HW acceleration** either:

- for a problematic View, with `myView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`
- for a particular OS version (e.g. all older than JB MR1), with [these tricks](https://plus.google.com/+AndroidDevelopers/posts/DcsFABkyuYM).

Source of info found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850259/is-there-a-way-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-only-for-android-4-0-3).

Comment: worked for me by invoking the setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); in my own Views constructor