# Android mapview (negative coloring)

Tags: android, android-mapview

I would like to draw a circle overlay in my android app, which I can ofcourse easily do and add a color to it as well.

But what I would really like to do is to keep the circle transparent and shade the outside of the circle (the rest of the world) with a light gray color.

I tried to add the circle as a path, shade the world and clip the circle out, but i get a bounding box around the circle on my device (although it looks fine on the emulator).

Any help appreciated. Below is a code snippet:

public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
    {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

```
    Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();

    Point pt = new Point();

    GeoPoint geo = new GeoPoint((int) (mLat * 1e6), (int) (mLon * 1e6));

    projection.toPixels(geo, pt);
    float circleRadius = projection.metersToEquatorPixels(mRadius)
            * (1 / FloatMath.cos((float) Math.toRadians(mLat)));

    Paint innerCirclePaint;

    innerCirclePaint = new Paint();
    innerCirclePaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    innerCirclePaint.setAlpha(35);
    innerCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    innerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);
    path.addCircle((float) pt.x, (float) pt.y, circleRadius, Path.Direction.CCW);canvas.drawPath(path, innerCirclePaint);
    canvas.drawARGB(150, 0, 0, 0 );
    canvas.clipPath(path);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor ("#88ff0000"));
```

Comment: are you suggesting that i simply change the color??
This doesn't work!

Comment: sorry .. have shadow on map?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? Can you please be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
```

instead of

```
path.setFillType(Path.FillType.WINDING);
```

I tried it for a normal image and this patch worked for me

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint innerCirclePaint;

    innerCirclePaint = new Paint();
    innerCirclePaint.setColor(Color.parseColor ("#88ff0000"));
    innerCirclePaint.setAlpha(35);
    innerCirclePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    innerCirclePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

    Path path = new Path();
    path.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
    path.addCircle(150, 150, 150, Path.Direction.CCW);

    canvas.drawPath(path, innerCirclePaint);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0 );
    canvas.clipPath(path);
```

And even clipPath could have been a reason

[Work around Canvas.clipPath() that is not supported in android any more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895677/work-around-canvas-clippath-that-is-not-supported-in-android-any-more)