# Custom View not being shown Android

Tags: android, testing, canvas

In my app I have a custom view where I am drawing a figure. The app runs fine in most of the devices (motog and tablets) but when i tested the app on a samsung duos my figure wasnt being shown.

**Edit**

I have found that the problem was with disabling the hardware acceleration for that view. Now the view is shown in the samsung device but however my canvas.clipPath() is not working. Is there any way to use canvas.clipPath() method without disabling hardware acceleration ?

Comment: We can't tell you anything without seeing some code or something...

Comment: okay found the problem - its bcause i had disabled the hardware acceleration for that view. Its now working in the samsung device. But however my canvas,clipPath is not working now. Is there any way of having hardware acceleration on and using canvas.clipPath ?

Comment: you should edit your question..have you checked this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895677/work-around-canvas-clippath-that-is-not-supported-in-android-any-more