# View distorted/blurred while using admob/amazon adds in Nexus 4

Tags: android, view, admob

In Nexus 4, when showing adds (admob or amazon's), a view that is added and moved touching the screen becomes distorted. If ads are not shown, there is no problem with the view.
There isn't any problem either in the emulator or in a galaxy IV.

I think that the problem could be somewhat related to the chrome renderer and its use of the egl driver, but no idea how to solve it.

A test view code with admob:

```
public class TestAdmob extends ViewGroup {
    private AdView adView;
    private Rect drawRect;
    private Test1 myView;

    public TestAdmob(Activity context, String adUnitId) {
        super(context);

        myView = new Test1(context);
        drawRect = new Rect(0, 0, 400, 400);

        adView = new AdView(context);
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                Log.d("Admob", "onAdLoaded");
                requestLayout();
            }
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) { Log.d("Admob", "failedToLoad " + errorCode); }
            public void onAdOpened() { Log.d("Admob", "adOpened"); }
            public void onAdClosed() { Log.d("Admob", "adClosed"); }
            public void onAdLeftApplication() { Log.d("Admob", "adLeftApp"); }
        });
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .build();

        addView(adView);

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    }

    private int getHeightAd() {
        try { return adView.getAdSize().getHeightInPixels(adView.getContext()); }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return 200;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        adView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(getHeightAd(), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
    }
    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        adView.layout(l, 0, r, getHeightAd());
        myView.layout(drawRect.left, drawRect.top, drawRect.right, drawRect.bottom);
    }

    @Override public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        drawRect.offsetTo((int)event.getX()-drawRect.width()/2, (int)event.getY()-drawRect.height()/2);
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            addView(myView);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            requestLayout();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
            removeView(myView);
        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
    private class Test1 extends View {
        Path path = new Path();
        Bitmap bitmap;

        public Test1(Context context) {
            super(context);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.anImage);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            path.lineTo(getWidth(), 0);
            path.lineTo(getWidth()/2, getHeight());
            path.moveTo(0, 0);
            canvas.clipPath(path);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);      }

    }
}
```

The distorted view when showing ads:
[image: distorted view]

and when not, as it should be:

[image: good view]

Comment: Any luck on this? I'm having the same issue as well.

Comment: No, no solution by now :(

Comment: It seems like this only happens on devices 4.4.3+. Even Android L has the same issue.

Comment: I got a solution. I hope it'll work for you too. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution. Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8895677/work-around-canvas-clippath-that-is-not-supported-in-android-any-more), I modified the code like this (added the setLayer line):

```
...
 }

 private class Test1 extends View {
    Path path = new Path();
    Bitmap bitmap;

    public Test1(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable. anImage);
    }
...
```