# How I can create rounded layout with two vertical line?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to put two vertical lines in a rounded layout (linear or relative)

Like this picture:

[image: layout with rounded corners, contains two vertical lines]

**EDIT:**

My try:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_bg"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <View
        android:layout_width="5dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

And Result:

[image: vertical line extending outside background with rounded corners]

Comment: start off with rounded corners. thats been talked about many time. then work on the lines. hint: itll all be done in XML.

Comment: @DroiDev Please help me with example.

Comment: @Zardchoobe please sstop being lazy. there are plenty of examples on here about rounded corders for android views.

Comment: @DroiDev I try this for 3 days. I want rounded line in rounded layout!!  This is a difficult task.

Comment: want an easier way? look into using a 9patch png. might be MUCH easier. dont yell at me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you need a transparent area outside of the rounded-corners background, masking the  excess parts of the vertical lines is not an option. In this case, you can use a custom `View` which will work for API levels 17+:

```
public class RoundedCornersLinearLayout extends LinearLayout{

        private Paint backgroundPaint;
        private Paint linePaint;

        private float cornerRadius;
        private float line_width;
        private float line_margin;
        private RectF rect = new RectF(0, 0, 0,0);

        private Path rectPath = new Path();
        private Path linePath = new Path();

        public RoundedCornersLinearLayout(Context context) {
            super(context);
            init();
        }

        public RoundedCornersLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }

        public RoundedCornersLinearLayout(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
            init();
        }

        private void init() {
            setWillNotDraw(false);

            // add this so Canvas.clipPath() will give the desired result also for devices running Api level 17,
            // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/30354461/5015207
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
            }
            backgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            backgroundPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
            linePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            linePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
            linePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

            // with  <dimen name="corner_radius">60dp</dimen> in res/values/dimens.xml
            cornerRadius = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.corner_radius);
            //  <dimen name="line_width">5dp</dimen>
            line_width =  getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_width);
            //  <dimen name="margin_10dp">10dp</dimen>
            line_margin = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_10dp);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        super.onLayout(changed, left, top, right, bottom);
        float measuredWidth = right - left;
        float measuredHeight = bottom - top;
        rect.set(0, 0, measuredWidth, measuredHeight);

        rectPath.reset();
        linePath.reset();

        rectPath.addRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
        linePath.addRect(measuredWidth - (line_margin + line_width), 0, measuredWidth - line_margin, measuredHeight, Path.Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rect, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, backgroundPaint);    
        canvas.clipPath(rectPath);
        canvas.drawPath(linePath, linePaint);
    }
}
```

Screenshots for Lollipop (emulator)...

[image]

... and Jellybean 4.2.2 (device):

[image]

Comment: CardView Clipping don't work on android 4.3 . only 5 and above it's ok.  I want only Linear or Relative layout.  I say in question.

Comment: @Zardchoobe - took me some time, but I thought this should be possible even on older devices - the new approach uses a custom View and works on Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Clipping is an expensive operation, and is only truly supported on Lollipop and higher.

If you're okay with Lollipop+ only, and really want to use a `RelativeLayout`, you can call `myView.setClipToOutline(true)`. If your `myView` has a rounded background, this will tell the system to clip all children to that rounded shape.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    myView.setClipToOutline(true);
}
```

If you need rounded corner clipping on pre-Lollipop versions, then the best thing to do is use an overlay to mask parts of the view you don't want to see. That is, create a drawable with *opaque* corners and a *transparent* center, and apply that **on top** of the views you want to clip. This won't actually clip your views, but it will provide the illusion of doing so.

More on this strategy here: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-round-corners-on-an-android-imageview-with-this-hack/