# How to accommodate image shape according to image view?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have an `ImageView` with rounded corners, but when I add the bitmap to it, the image doesn't have rounded corners

I have a module where I capture images, I want these images to always take the shape of the `ImageView`, in this case, the rounded corners, as seen in the image below.

[image]

XML (this is the card)

`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="185dp"
    android:layout_height="185dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/im_producto"
            android:layout_weight=".8"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners_top"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_eliminar_fotografía"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".2"
            android:text="Eliminar"
            android:background="@drawable/bg_rounded_corners_bottom"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/purple_two"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

`

JAVA
in the java part, I just use the set bitmap method and add the bitmap of the image

Comment: does this answers your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1705239/how-should-i-give-images-rounded-corners-in-android